# Can I filter warnings when building from Android Studio to Xcode for iOS with Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, filter, build, warnings

I am running a command line to compile my Flutter project from Android Studio, with Xcode 13.3.1.

Today I use "Flutter build ipa --release". Unfortunately it seems that I have an Xcode error, the archive is not created.

In the log, I have a hundred warnings that pop, and I can't find the error. Is it possible to add an argument to the command line to filter the warnings during the build?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, with -v added, errors are printed in red.